# Haproxy 1.7 url rewriting reqrep doesn't work

Tags: rewrite, haproxy

I'm currently trying to rewrite url based on extensions and subdomains, but my update doesn't work, so I will try to explain my procedure:

I would like to rewrite this kind of url

```
https://mydomain.tld/image.jpg
```

to

```
https://jpg.mydomain.tld/image
```

so I update my haproxy.cfg and add to my frontend these rules:

```
frontend web
    bind *:80
    acl p_ext_jpg path_end -i .jpg
    acl p_ext_png path_end -i .png
    acl mydomain hdr(host) -i mydomain.tld
    reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /(*).(jpg|png)     \1\ /\2
    use_backend backend_static if  p_ext_jpg p_ext_png mydomain
    default_backend backend_web
```

My current nginx rule who work:

```
rewrite "^/([0-9]+).(jpg|png)$" $scheme://$2.mydomain.tld/$1;
```

My current problems:

1. I don't know how to replace mydomain by (jpg|png).mydomain
2. any reqrep seems not be used by my haproxy

I only want to rewrite url and forward to my backend not redirection.

Thanks for your help and sorry for my english.

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but you're going to need to use some combination of `http-request` directives because you're making changes to more than just a single header here (as your `reqrep` is doing). You'll probably need to use `http-request` with `set-uri`, `set-path`, `set-uri`, `set-header`, or `replace-header`.

Answer (score 0):

Your backend is never used because your "if" is an implicit AND. Use an "or":

```
use_backend backend_static if mydomain { p_ext_jpg or p_ext_png }
```

And so you can rewrite the host:

```
reqirep ^Host:\ mydomain.tld Host:\ jpg.mydomain.tld if mydomain p_ext_jpg
reqirep ^Host:\ mydomain.tld Host:\ png.mydomain.tld if mydomain p_ext_png
```

"http-request" is a "newer" way to solve this...

Comment: is it also possible to remove the port number from the url?

Comment: the port number is in the host header - so yes... you can... [haproxy docu](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#4.2-reqrep)  
  
example url: http://example.com:12345/bla.html  
`reqirep ^Host:\ example.com:12345 Host:\ example.com`

Comment: `reqirep` was not recognized on my haproxy 1.6

Comment: http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4.2-reqirep